# script Setnamed range howto get whole column?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get a named range based on the text a user types in. In the script below I can create a named range, only the range is just the cell I typed in. I want to have the full column for example: A1:A (or the last available row)

I am struggeling with the "setNamedRange" itself. Anyone any hints?

```
function onEdit2(e) {
    const range = e.range;
  let current_cell =range.getA1Notation();
  let value_selected = sheet.getRange(current_cell).getValue();
  let value_selectedform = sheet.getRange(current_cell).getDataValidations();  
  col = range.getColumn();

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let first = ss.getSheetByName("categorie");

  console.log(first.getMaxRows()); // 10
  console.log(first.getLastRow()); // 5

  ss.setNamedRange(value_selected, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange());
```

I found the working code bewlow to get a idea. But I want this "on the fly"

```
function headerNamedRanges() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const hA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  hA.forEach((h, i) => {
    let rg = sh.getRange(2, i + 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).activate();
    Logger.log(h);
    ss.setNamedRange(h, ss.getActiveRange());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got something working. But it could use a cleanup.

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  const range = e.range;
  let current_cell =range.getA1Notation();
  let value_selected = sheet.getRange(current_cell).getValue();
  let value_selectedform = sheet.getRange(current_cell).getDataValidations();  
  col = range.getColumn();
  nrrow = range.getLastRow();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  var nrrow2 = r.getRow();
   var activerow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(activerow);
  
  if (activerow == 1){

  let rg = sh.getRange(2,col,100,1).activate();  //1e = row, 2e = col 3 =
  ss.setNamedRange(value_selected, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()); //werkt
  }}
```